# Linux: Is it possible to add file protocol support on remote host?

Tags: linux, cross-platform, protocols

I have a file `test.txt` on remote host `myhost`.

In Windows I can access the file using this URL: `file://myhost/test.txt` and `myhost` can be viewed in my `Network`

However, it seems that Linux is using a different protocol to access this URL.

I tried to use the same URL but it cannot find the file.
I am guessing maybe it is because `myhost` is not mounted in Linux.

Is it possible to add file protocol support on **remote** host without mounting it or installing extra packages?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In eg. nautilus in GNOME, you can use the `smb` protocol. Example:  `smb://domain;user@server/share`

Comment: in Nautilus go to menu Go/Location and enter the address in above mentioned form... it does work on my computer

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have SMB protocol installed on my Linux machine

Comment: you most likely miss `libgnomevfs2-extra` package (the name depends on your distribution / the mentioned is valid for `debian`)